# "lftp" login still possible for "/etc/pam.d/vsftpd" blocked users

Tags: ftp, lftp

I have a ftp server running on the machine 192.168.122.50

Below are the last three directives from /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf file

```
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#userlist_enable=YES
#userlist_deny=YES
```

Below is the content of /etc/pam.d/vsftpd file

```
#%PAM-1.0
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so    force revoke
auth       required     pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers onerr=succeed
auth       required     pam_shells.so
auth       include      password-auth
account    include      password-auth
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    include      password-auth
```

Below is the content of the /etc/vsftpd/ftpusers file

```
#This is the list of blocked users as per the following line /etc/pam.d/vsftpd
#auth required pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers onerr=succeed

root
bin
daemon
adm
lp
sync
shutdown
halt
mail
news
uucp
operator
games
nobody
```

So two users, for example, `root` should be blocked from accessing the ftp server at this machine and `ssam` should be allowed.

Now from client machine 192.168.0.2, I tried this.

```
am@centos ~]$ ftp 192.168.122.50
Connected to 192.168.122.50 (192.168.122.50).
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
Name (192.168.122.50:ssam): ssam    
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> exit
221 Goodbye.
[ssam@centos ~]$ ftp 192.168.122.50
Connected to 192.168.122.50 (192.168.122.50).
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
Name (192.168.122.50:ssam): root
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
530 Login incorrect.
Login failed.
ftp> bye
221 Goodbye.
```

The output was inline with the **pam** settings as the user `ssam` was allowed and user `root` was blocked.

Now I have tried the lftp command at the client to connect to the server for the user root.

```
[ssam@centos ~]$ lftp root@192.168.122.50
Password: 
lftp root@192.168.122.50:~>
```

The login was indeed possible **blocked** user  `root` as I got the lftp prompt. Now I tried to run a command.

```
lftp root@192.168.122.50:~>
ls: Login failed: 530 Login incorrect.
```

Now it seems like the server has come to good senses and it tells me I was not able to do anything else. But the pluggable authentication module should have blocked the user `root` from entering the server at the first instance.

Could anybody explain this for me?

Comment: IMO, it's a way how lftp client works. Check the log file /var/log/secure (on RHEL/CentOS) or similar for events like "pam_listfile(vsftpd:auth): Refused user root for service vsftpd".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, it's a way how `lftp` client works. Check the log file `/var/log/secure` (on RHEL/CentOS) or similar for events like

```
pam_listfile(vsftpd:auth): Refused user root for service vsftpd
```

I verified such behavior by sniffing FTP traffic (RHEL 6.x, vsftpd 2.2.2, lftp 4.0.9). The FTP connection is not established till you enter some valid FTP command (aka `ls`) and not when you enter user name and its password.

Comment: @dsmask80 : Thank You. Me too got `pam_listfile(vsftpd:auth): Refused user root for service vsftpd` in the log. Looks like lftp caches the username and password, and gives a formal sub-prompt, which made me misjudge that an actual connection is established. It tries to make the actual  connection only when you enter a valid command. I checked the time when I enter the command and it matches the refusal time in the log.

Answer (score -1):

```
vim /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

Come on second last line.... `userlist_enable="NO"`

Save it and after that

```
# vim /etc/vsftpd/ftpusers
```

remove the "root" user from it...in this file

Users that are not allowed to login via ftp.
Save it and restart the service.
I hope it will work.....

Comment: The question isn't about server configuration, sjsam has already done this.